# Exception In Python Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am beginner to python and I have doubt in one program when using try except part
I try to take input from user and add that number by 1 like if you enter 5 then 6 will be printed but if you enter string then except would come in role and print enter only number
I've written code but except is not working there, code is working like if I enter 5 then 6 gets printed but except statement is not working

Here is the code that I've written

```
def increment(num):
    try:
        return num + 1

    except Exception as e:
        print("ufff error occured :", e)

n = int(input("enter your num: "))
a = increment(n)
print(a)
```

Comment: The exception is raised from the `int()` conversion which is not protected by a `try/except`

Comment: what should i do can you copy paste me correct code

Comment: move the `int` conversion inside the funciton... `return int(num) + 1`

Comment: wow, sir thank you very much appreciate you i got stucked in this from past 1 day and i was frustrated what the hell s happening, now you solved it in seconds

Comment: but now in output in last there is "none", why is it so

Comment: Instead of `print("ufff error occured :", e)` simply `return "ufff error occured : {}".format(e)`

Comment: yes it worked out thanks everyone, but can anyone tell what should i have to do if i use int with input line what changes i've to make

Comment: Put it also inside the function?

Comment: def increment(num):
    try:
        return num + 1
        n = int(input("enter your num: "))

    except Exception as e:
        print("ufff error occured :", e)

    finally:
        print('we are done')

# n = (input("enter your num: "))
a = increment(n)
print(a)

Comment: now i have added that input with int in try catch what's problem now

Comment: It's really not possible to read that. Either [edit] the question or ask a new one

Comment: i have edited code in question can you check sir

Comment: Well that line is not reachable... There is no point in putting code after a `return`... Please check my answer to clarify things

Comment: i have edited code again is it what you were trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change to the following:

```
def increment(num):
    try:
        return int(num) + 1

    except Exception as e:
        print("ufff error occured :", e)

n = input("enter your num: ")
a = increment(n)
print(a)
```

The reason for that is that the exception was raised by the int() functions, because it couldn't convert your input to int. The call to int() was before the increment function. Therefore the exception was unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

You tried converting the input to `int` before going into the `try/except` block. If you just put it in the `try` block it will work.

```
def increment(num):
    try:
        num = int(num)
        return num + 1

    except Exception as e:
        print("ufff error occured :", e)


n = input("enter your num: ")
a = increment(n)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend the following?

```py
def increment(num):
    try:
        return int(num) + 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("ufff error occurred:", e)

n = input("enter your num: ")
a = increment(n)
print(a)
```

The only difference here is that the attempt to convert the user's input to an `int` occurs within the `try-except` block, rather than outside. This allows the type conversion error to be caught and your message ("ufff error occurred: ...") to be displayed.

---

Edit: regarding your comment:

> yes it worked out thanks everyone, but can anyone tell what should i have to do if i use int with input line what changes i've to make

Optionally, you could do the following:

```py
def increment(num):
    return num + 1


try:
    n = int(input("enter your num: "))
    a = increment(n)
    print(a)
except Exception as e:
    print("ufff error occurred:", e)
```

In this case, I would recommend removing the `try-except` block in the `increment` function, because you can safely assume that all values passed to that function will be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use the type conversion within the try block so that if `num` is not a number, the controller would move to expect portion.
   The problem here is you are using type conversion outside of `try-catch` block.
2. Another point to note, convert `e` to string as a good practice.
3. Third point to note,the last line `print(a)` will itself cause trouble in cases of exception as you have returned nothing from the exception part and directly printed the error. Use a `return` statement in there else it would return `None` type and which itself will mess up the flow.

```
def increment(num):
    try:
        return int(num) + 1        #Updated Line

    except Exception as e:
        return "ufff error occurred :" + str(e)   #Updated Line

n = input("enter your num: ")
a = increment(n)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only code that would raise an exception is the `int(...)` conversion - and it is not protected under a `try/except` block. You should put it under the `try`:

```py
def increment():
    try:
        return int(input("enter your num: ")) + 1
    except ValueError as e:
        return f"ufff error occured: {e}"

print(increment())
```

You should always try to catch the narrowest exception. In this case, a `ValueError`.